# Pass arguments to a PHP file when using http.post('phpfile.php') in Angular

Tags: php, angular, http

I am using Angular and I have post request in my .ts file that calls a PHP file in my project. I would like to pass some arguments so I can use them in that PHP file.

Here is my HTTP post request

`this.http.post('http:localhost/api.php');`

How can I pass some variables into this so I can use them in the `api.php` file?

Comment: `this.http.post('http:localhost/api.php');` doesn't look like PHP code to me.

Comment: I recommend looking into www.slimframework.com which is a microframework that handles API requests. Also POST requests typically have a body which can contain arguments. Also you can use query parameters on the URI to pass in any `label=value` arguments.

Comment: @simon sorry you are right i will edit my question to explain it better

Comment: Send data/parameters as POST values or straight json to php://input